# Cannot start Kafka because of log file used by another process?

Tags: apache-kafka

I downloaded Kafka and run it on my local Windows for testing/development. It worked for a couple of days and now it gets the following error. I tried to use process explorer and the file is not used by any process except the time when Kafka is starting (java.exe).

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs\my-replicated-topic-0\00000000000000000000.log -> C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs\my-replicated-topic-0\00000000000000000000.log.deleted: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

```
[2018-05-14 11:25:35,965] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=0] Finished loading offsets and group metadata from __consumer_offsets-48 in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2018-05-14 11:26:04,864] INFO [Log partition=my-replicated-topic-0, dir=C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs] Found deletable segments with base offsets [0] due to retention time 604800000ms breach (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-05-14 11:26:04,869] INFO [Log partition=my-replicated-topic-0, dir=C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs] Scheduling log segment [baseOffset 0, size 150] for deletion. (kafka.log.Log)
[2018-05-14 11:26:04,882] ERROR Error while deleting segments for my-replicated-topic-0 in dir C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs\my-replicated-topic-0\00000000000000000000.log -> C:\tools\kafka_2.12-1.1.0\kafka-logs\my-replicated-topic-0\00000000000000000000.log.deleted: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka: unable to start Kafka - process can not access file 00000000000000000000.timeindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599625/kafka-unable-to-start-kafka-process-can-not-access-file-00000000000000000000)