# Spring Kafka test with embedded Kafka failed on deleting logs

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I am using spring kafka with the embedded kafka for JUnit test, it gives an error for every test on windows:

```
Error deleting C:\Users:LXX691\AppData\Local\Temp\kafka-1103610162480947200/.lock: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I just did the basic configuration like below

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class KafkaTest {
  @Autowired
  EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

  @Before
  void setUp() throws Exception() {
    // setup producer and consumers
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("topic", "content"));
  }
}
```

Any suggestion to resolve or any workaround is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any workaround to make the test pass, as this is a known issue which we cant handle?

Comment: I don't think it will make the test faile.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in Apache Kafka: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8145.

Unfortunately there is nothing in Spring Kafka we can do on the matter.

See more info here: [Kafka: unable to start Kafka - process can not access file 00000000000000000000.timeindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599625/kafka-unable-to-start-kafka-process-can-not-access-file-00000000000000000000) and here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/194