# Organize co-working for Kafka and Zookeeper using systemd

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, systemd

I've installed Kafka on a VM and want to launch it on VM startup and turn it off on shutdown.
It would be a quite simple task, but Kafka relies on working Zookeeper service.

Dependency on startup can be configured using capabilities of Systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Kafka Server
Documentation=http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html
Requires=zookeeper.service
```

But I couldn't find how to configure shutdown order, I need to stop Kafka first and only after that stop Zookeeper, otherwise Kafka didn't de-register itself from it properly, and fails with the following error on the next startup:

**ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/1001, node already exists and owner '100620751232642057' does not match current session '100626285143549184' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)**

Could you suggest how can I arrange the shutdown order for Systemd units?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait between ZooKeeper and Kafka by setting ExecStartPre.

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 20
```

Refer to [error while starting kafka broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759071/)